# Does a WiFi client vary the strength of the signal it emits?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, wifi-configuration, mobile-phone

I am using a metal container to dampen my WiFi router in the hope of reducing its radiation health risks.

I'm wondering if the client device might increase its own emitted signal strength to compensate for the weakened RSSI it detects?

If so then my effort to dampen the signal may have the opposite effect.

Thanks.

Comment: There are no known health risks from wifi routers.  Yes, they do vary emitted strength, so by putting it in a can, you are making it put out a stronger signal, so if you don't block it entirely, you will end up with the same amount of radiation from it, and more from clients.

Comment: why aren't you turning off your wi-fi and using cables?

Comment: @user253751  That's what I'm doing now, most of the time.

Comment: You can log into the router's settings page and turn off wi-fi completely. Then you don't need the metal container

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First your wireless router in a metal container will NOT be compensated by the Wireless card. That will not happen.

Second, there are competing articles, but one common thread is that radiation must be of the ionizing kind to be a health risk.

5 GHz Wireless is not ionizing radiation and is generally considered to be safe.

[Wireless radiation](https://ask.imeshforce.com/en/articles/2508878-is-5ghz-wifi-safe-and-healthy-is-it-better-to-stay-on-2-4ghz-only)

> Radiation that actually causes issues, could potentially cause cancer,
> etc., is usually ionizing radiation. It has a very high frequency and
> can cause mutations in DNA, possibly leading to cancer (more info on
> that process). The frequency required to be ionizing? At least
> 1,000,000 GHz. That is literally a 500,000 times higher frequency than
> what Wi-Fi transmits on, 2.4 GHz or 5 GHz. Non-ionizing radiation,
> which Wi-Fi falls under, does little more than transfer heat.

Lots of people use 5 GHz wireless, and I think we would know about it in the senior news magazines if radiation from wireless were harmful.

Comment: Overall cancer rates have been increasing for decades, for mysterious reasons.

Comment: @YanKingYin i'd be more worried about PFAS in the rainwater, than radio waves

Comment: Are cancer rates going up, or early cancer detection and prevention going up?  Mind your statistics.  At any rate, it's not radio waves causing it.